# How to permanently seal a pipe filled with water and under pressure making it equal to the wall?

Tags: plumbing

What I'm trying to do is something like this:
[image]

I don't want any section of the pipe out of the wall. So I can't use a common "external" cap. I need a cap that goes inside the pipe (or something else).

After sealed, the pipe will still be filled with water and under normal pressure for the kind of pipe. It will be a dead leg.

I'm trying to avoid breaking walls to change the pressure valve or cap the pipe.

Comment: Why? I strongly suspect you are jumping to an incorrect solution to your real problem.

Comment: These are used to test drain vents (as in roof vents) in new construction. They are evidently cemented in enabling the system to be tested under some pressure but a lot less than the pressure of water supply.  When the test is over the center is knocked out or cut out leaving a ring still adhering to the inside of the drain pipe end. I think the tab is designed to allow yanking out the plug with pliers. They are absolutely not approved to seal a pvc water pipe or even as a permanent seal in a sanitary sewer pipe.

Comment: Is this a water supply pipe or a drain pipe? You can't be cagey on this site. To get help you have to give the context and purpose of what you are asking about.

Comment: You cannot improvise on potable water supply piping. There are strict code requirements. What diameter is the pipe? Would this turn into a 'dead leg'. Water can sometimes stagnate in such cases, get depleted of residual chlorine, and allow bacteria to grow.  I'm not up on plumbing design but it would help if you would describe the situation in detail.

Comment: @JimStewart Now I get it. The central part of the test cap is easily removable with a hammer. So it's not strong enough for water. It also explains why I can't find them in plumbing retailers.

Comment: @JimStewart I'm a bit confused with the technical terms. It's a pipe for an old toilet flush valve. It will be a "dead leg". I mean if a dead leg is when other sections of the pipe will still be used.

Comment: I don't know of any approved internal plugs for potable water piping, nor how to deal with modifications which create a dead leg.  To get info from more knowledgeable people edit your question to explain in detail the current arrangement and what you want to change it to.

Comment: "under normal pressure"... need more data. They make internal plugs that insert, then expand; they are *perfectly acceptable* for sewer and vent lines which see very little pressure but not acceptable for higher pressures like those found in drinking water supply systems. **What is the line?**

Comment: Far from "discussing the philosophy of perfect scientific plumbing" is a simple request to find the nature of the line service, as requested by everyone who commented, so we can give an appropriate answer. *Thank you* for revealing that it is a toilet/sewer line. You are now likely to receive various answers to help you.

Comment: As I understand the OP's comments now in the question as edited this was the **water supply** to a toilet now removed, and is connected to the potable water supply of the structure. I am not aware of any internal plugs for potable water supply pipes.

Comment: Why does this have to be filled? Why does this have to be capped?  Just patch past it and ignore it.

Comment: @keshlam _Why does this have to be filled?_ It doesn't. Do you have any alternative? _Why does this have to be capped?_ To stop water from flooding the bathroom. _Just patch past it and ignore it_ Could you explain this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now we are getting somewhere. You have a pressure flushing system which is malfunctioning, and I can understand your desire to remedy this.

But your solution is too radical. The first attempt should be to get a better pressure system and not to do radical surgery on your existing piping. Can't you replace the valving with a better quality one? Tank (aka cistern) flushing systems have their own problems.

Is this an emergency? Have you removed the toilet and this is your only one?

Comment: I think exposing the end of the pipe inside the wall and using an external cap will do it. I insist it can't project past a certain point because I need the tiny space left between the wall and the toilet to put the new pipe for flushing.

Comment: What is the material around the end of the pipe? Is it concrete? You should explain in detail the context of your question? That is, what is the situation as it is and what do you wish to have in its place. If you would describe this, someone may come up with a solution that would never occur to you.  I would like to know if this would be a dead leg, how long would it be to where the water flows?

Comment: Why are you eliminating a perfectly good water supply line and replacing it with another?

Comment: The OP should give a picture of the entire bathroom and he has the annotation ability to show exactly what the situation is.

Comment: @JimStewart I edited the question again. Take a look.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: If you would want to change to a cistern flush, you would probably use the existing pipe to fill the cistern. In the US they are filled from below. Don't cut off this pipe! What is the construction of the wall behind the toilet? concrete or wood frame?

Comment: When I lived in Fiji in 1969-70 we had a tank up about 6 or 7 ft above the toilet. It would really flush. The flushing was accomplished by a pull chain that one had to give a vigorous arm pull on because the mechanism started a siphon as opposed to a simple downward drain. This meant that there was no flapper valve to leak. Of course, there was still a ballcock or similiar to fill the tank and shut off the flow when the tank was full.

Comment: So you have a mechanism like this https://www.americanstandard-us.com/-/media/sites/asus/images/products/commercial-toilets/madera-16-gpf-ada-toilet-with-exposed-manual-flush-valve-system-2857016/2857016020-madera-toilet-with-exposed-manual-flush-valve-system.png?w=300&hash=EAD55407E0FE6C9A54F62D226F025E1EB3037416 . What is the brand of the flush valve you have?

Comment: @JimStewart I'm going to use the existing pipe to fill the cistern (in fact the pressure valve). And yes, it'll be filled from below. My drawing is a simplification. If I don't cut the pipe, I can't put the new pipe coming from the cistern.

Comment: @JimStewart Yeah, we still use the pull chain (actually a string) in Brazil. But it's becoming rare. If this cistern doesn't work I'll install one of these http://www.tigre.com.br/kit-sanitario-plena

Comment: @JimStewart No, I have no mechanism like the one in the picture. Again, my drawing is a simplification. It's a common toilet. No water entry from the above. The valve is 25+ years old. Not manufactured anymore. After repair with new pieces, it works for only 6 months.

Comment: Can you remove the existing pressure flush valve and put in a new pressure flush valve? How did you arrive at the decision to change to a cistern? I would think that changing to a new model pressure flush valve would be the  usual procedure. Are other people changing the pressure valve flush to cistern?

Comment: @JimStewart I'm avoiding breaking any concrete or ceramic. There is a consensus in the country that valves are a waste of water. Virtually any new (or not so new) building comes only with cistern flush. We are in the beginning of the sixth consecutive year of drought. Some have already made the change of the entire toilet for a cistern one. Which means breaking walls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51447/discussion-between-jim-stewart-and-gustavo).